# How to translate StreamWriter/StreamReader functionality to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, code-conversion

I am working on translating a large code base written in C# to ansi C++ (**not** C++/CLI) that has to be able to run both on Linux and Windows. So has to be standard (and without the use of third party libraries such as boost since it's against company policy). 
I manage to convert almost the entire project, but thee are parts that use

```
StreamWriter, FileStream
```

objects, and i am nut sure how to translate their functionality to pure C++?

There are two separate questions:
1) Design wise - do i completely replace the `StreamWriter`, `FileStream` code in my project and put different code that does the same thing, or do i create my own   `StreamWriter`, `FileStream` classes and implement the same functionality and this way the original code can stay the same. I am leaning towards the second approach. 
2) My main issues is - how to replace `FileStream .Read()` and `StreamWriter.WriteLine` functionality? Is there an online C++ equivalent implementation or do i have to implement it from scratch? That seems like a big undertaking that's gonna take lots of time.

Comment: Your company is doing things wrong. Sometimes the cheapest solution in the short range is the most expensive in the long range. Instead of converting code without documenting it, it should be documented before conversion. That is more expensive in the short term but will save in the long run. As it is, it will be expensive for them to determine any mistakes in the conversion. I hope they have an adequate amount of test cases.

Comment: Take a look at [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/) and [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) in [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library).

Comment: Thanks @ yms i'll take a look at those. Any other tips from people as to how to translate those objects to standard C++ will be appreciated.